# The argument type 'Sound' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

I am trying to convert JSON to a dart list.

I have this class

```
class Sound {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String about;
  final List<String> album;

  Sound(
      {required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.about,
      required this.album});

  factory Sound.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Sound(
      id: json["id"],
      name: json["name"],
      about: json["about"],
      album: List<String>.from(json["album"]),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the `WebServices` class

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:sound/data/model/model.dart';

import '../../constants/strings.dart';

class SoundsWebServices {
  late Dio dio;

  SoundsWebServices() {
    BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: "http://10.0.2.2:8000/list/",
      receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
      connectTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 60), // 60 seconds,
      receiveTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
    );

    dio = Dio(options);
  }
  Future<List<Sound>> getAllSounds() async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.get('Album/');
      print(response.data.toString());

      return response.data ;
    } catch (e) {
      print("aniba");
      print(e.toString());
      return [];
    }
  }
}
```

And finally this the Repository

```
import '../model/model.dart';
import '../web_services/sounds_wev_services.dart';

class SoundsRepository {
  final SoundsWebServices soundsWebServices;

  SoundsRepository(this.soundsWebServices);

  Future<List<Sound>> getAllSounds() async {
    final sounds = await soundsWebServices.getAllSounds();
    return sounds.map((sound) => Sound.fromJson(sound)).toList();
  }
}
```

The problem is with the class `SoundsRepository`. I get this error:

> The argument type `Sound` can't be assigned to the parameter type `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in your `getAllSounds` function which does not return List as required by the function.

sounds like the `response.data` is of type `List<dynamic>` (if your API from the backend is designed to return the array directly).

so you need to do some serializations to make your getAllSounds return the correct `List<Sound>`.

```dart
  Future<List<Sound>> getAllSounds() async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.get('Album/');
      print(response.data.toString());

      //Make sure that the API returns an array directly. if it returns an array but in a specific key, you need to do `final list = response.data['key'];`
      final list = response.data;

      return list.map ((e) => Sound.fromJson(e)).toList();

    } catch (e) {
      print("aniba");
      print(e.toString());
      return [];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours **SoundWebService.getAllSounds** method already returns the data as a **Future<List>** so you do not need to do a mapping here.

```
class SoundsRepository {
  final SoundsWebServices soundsWebServices;

  SoundsRepository(this.soundsWebServices);

  Future<List<Sound>> getAllSounds() async {
    return await soundsWebServices.getAllSounds();
  }
}
```

But you have to do the mapping inside the **SoundWebService.getAllSounds** methods, depending on how the **response.data** looks like.